# Beat the compiler

Tags: c++, intel, intrinsics, avx

I'm trying to use Intel intrinsics to beat the compiler optimized code.  Sometimes I can do it, other times I can't.

I guess the question is, *why can I sometimes beat the compiler, but other times not*?  I got a time of 0.006 seconds for `operator+=` below using Intel intrinsics, (vs 0.009 when using bare C++), but a time of 0.07 s for `operator+` using intrinsics, while bare C++ was only 0.03 s.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

class Timer
{
  LARGE_INTEGER startTime ;
  double fFreq ;

public:
  Timer() {
    LARGE_INTEGER freq ;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency( &freq ) ;
    fFreq = (double)freq.QuadPart ;
    reset();
  }

  void reset() {   QueryPerformanceCounter( &startTime ) ;  }

  double getTime() {
    LARGE_INTEGER endTime ;
    QueryPerformanceCounter( &endTime ) ;
    return ( endTime.QuadPart - startTime.QuadPart ) / fFreq ; // as double
  }
} ;


inline float randFloat(){
  return (float)rand()/RAND_MAX ;
}



// Use my optimized code,
#define OPTIMIZED_PLUS_EQUALS
#define OPTIMIZED_PLUS

union Vector
{
  struct { float x,y,z,w ; } ;
  __m128 reg ;

  Vector():x(0.f),y(0.f),z(0.f),w(0.f) {}
  Vector( float ix, float iy, float iz, float iw ):x(ix),y(iy),z(iz),w(iw) {}
  //Vector( __m128 val ):x(val.m128_f32[0]),y(val.m128_f32[1]),z(val.m128_f32[2]),w(val.m128_f32[3]) {}
  Vector( __m128 val ):reg( val ) {} // 2x speed, above

  inline Vector& operator+=( const Vector& o ) {
    #ifdef OPTIMIZED_PLUS_EQUALS
    // YES! I beat it!  Using this intrinsic is faster than just C++.
    reg = _mm_add_ps( reg, o.reg ) ;
    #else
    x+=o.x, y+=o.y, z+=o.z, w+=o.w ;
    #endif
    return *this ;
  }

  inline Vector operator+( const Vector& o )
  {
    #ifdef OPTIMIZED_PLUS
    // This is slower
    return Vector( _mm_add_ps( reg, o.reg ) ) ;
    #else
    return Vector( x+o.x, y+o.y, z+o.z, w+o.w ) ;
    #endif
  }

  static Vector random(){
    return Vector( randFloat(), randFloat(), randFloat(), randFloat() ) ;
  }

  void print() {

    printf( "%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", x,y,z,w ) ;
  }
} ;

int runs = 8000000 ;
Vector sum ;

// OPTIMIZED_PLUS_EQUALS (intrinsics) runs FASTER 0.006 intrinsics, vs 0.009 (std C++)
void test1(){
  for( int i = 0 ; i < runs ; i++ )
    sum += Vector(1.f,0.25f,0.5f,0.5f) ;//Vector::random() ;
}

// OPTIMIZED* runs SLOWER (0.03 for reg.C++, vs 0.07 for intrinsics)
void test2(){
  float j = 27.f ;
  for( int i = 0 ; i < runs ; i++ )
  {
    sum += Vector( j*i, i, i/j, i ) + Vector( i, 2*i*j, 3*i*j*j, 4*i ) ;
  }
}

int main()
{
  Timer timer ;

  //test1() ;
  test2() ;

  printf( "Time: %f\n", timer.getTime() ) ;
  sum.print() ;

}
```

### Edit

Why am I doing this?  The VS 2012 profiler is telling me my vector arithmetic operations could use some tuning.

[image]

Comment: I bet it depends on the cache architecture and locality of reference. Only

Comment: What are those things?  Care to explain?  Also does that mean generally you should avoid using intrinsics?  Or is it due to the simplicity of the `test` loop I'm using?

Comment: The opcodes are only a small part of code performance. A large factor here may be cache lines, (false) sharing, memory access patterns (prefetch or not) etc. Also, getting things in and out of SIMD registers takes time. This means that 'simply using intrinsics' isn't always better.

Comment: why you use `float` arithmetic while you can use `int32_t`?

Comment: Because an algebraic `Vector` class generally won't use just integers,

Comment: @sehe So does that mean I _should_ or _shouldn't_ optimize a general Vector class.  It seems I am hurting the compiler's ability to optimize when I manually use intrinsics, which is kind of at the root of this question.

Comment: @bobobobo It's not about `should or shouldn't optimize`. You _should_ optimize if your profiler tells you. ***But*** you _should_ optimize based on what the profiler tells you, instead of 'blanket assumptions' (_X is better than Y_). In this case, you might be able to optimize by analyzing CPU cache performance. `cachegrind` might be a very valuable tool here

Comment: The testing framework is flawed. Your parameters have multiplications and divisions. Those will almost certainly take up the majority of the run-time. Secondly, you're populating new vectors in each iteration using the `union` hack. Constructing a SIMD vector using a `union` hack is very expensive if you use the result immediately. (by immediately, I mean within 20+ cycles)

Comment: @Mysticial But that is the fastest way I could find to get my operands into the register.  Casting `_mm_add_ps( *(__m128*)this, *(__m128*)&o )` I found to be marginally slower, and creating temporaries was _much_ slower. How else would you get your data into the register?

Comment: @bobobobo Currently, you're making two vectors and doing one addition. A better test would be to test 1000+ additions for each vector that is made. That should help offset the overhead of building the vectors.

Comment: @Mysticial Actually that worked.  Using `sum += t + t ;` (where `t` is defined outside the loop as some random floats) in `test2()` gets the time down to 0.007 seconds for intrinsics (versus 0.009 seconds for plain C++)

Comment: There's still more room for improvement. As the processor can do multiple operations at the same time provided that they are independent. But that can't really be exploited via a `Vector` class. It needs to be done on the user-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by Mysticial, the union hack is the most likely culprit in `test2`. It forces the data to go through L1 cache, which, while fast, has some latency that is much more than your gain of 2 cycles that the vector code offers (see below).

But also consider that the CPU can run multiple instructions out of order and in parallel (superscalar CPU). For example, Sandy Bridge has 6 execution units, p0--p5, floating point multiplication/division runs on p0, floating point addition and integer multiplication runs on p1. Also, division takes 3-4 times more cycles then multiplication/addition, and is not pipelined (i.e. the execution unit cannot start another instruction while division is being performed). So in `test2`, while the vector code is waiting for the expensive division and some multiplications to finish on unit p0, the scalar code can be performing the extra 2 add instructions on p1, which most likely obliterates any advantage of vector instructions.

`test1` is different, the constant vector can be stored in `xmm` register and in that case the loop contains only the add instruction. But the code is not 3x faster as might be expected. The reason is pipelined instructions: each add instruction has latency 3 cycles, but the CPU can start a new one every cycle when they are independent of each other. This is the case of the per-component vector addition. Therefore the vector code executes one add instruction per loop iteration with 3 cycle latency, and the scalar code executes 3 add instructions, taking only 5 cycles (1 started/cycle, and the 3rd has latency 3: 2 + 3 = 5).

A very good resource on CPU architectures and optimization is http://www.agner.org/optimize/